# How to use JS/Jquery to replaces repeated CSS styles - Nested List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

I am making a nested list and would like the hover styles to cover the full width of its container. In order to do this I am removing the default margin from the ul and applying padding-left to a div inside the li but it means having a lot of inefficient code. See below or [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/MKK8v/24/)

```
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0;}
li > div:hover { background-color: #eee}

li div{padding-left:0px}
li li div{padding-left:20px}
li li li div{padding-left:40px}
li li li li div{padding-left:60px}
```

I cannot continue to apply these styles as I am creating a file tree so the hierachy could go on forever. Does anyone know of an effecient way that I can do this in jQuery? Many thanks

Comment: Do you already have it set up to dynamically add the li tags to your html (so that they only thing you need to do is style it)?

Comment: Do you mean to include inline style with every li that is added? I would prefer a method that could count each li and give the appropriate padding to the span directly inside it. Maybe I didnt understand you?

Comment: No I was just wondering how much of the problem you'd already solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a little code that will do what you want :

```
$('div:not(:first)').each(function(){
    var numEl = $(this).parentsUntil('div:first', 'ul').length - 1;
    $(this).css('padding-left', numEl * 20 +'px')
})
```

It count the number of `ul` until you hit the root and the add the padding.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MKK8v/26/

**EDIT :**

Due to perfomance problems, here an optimised code 10 times faste :

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.parents('ul').length == 0 ? 0 : getIndex($this);
    $this.data('index', index);
})

function getIndex(el){
    return parseInt(el.parents('ul').first().data('index'))+1
}

$('div:not(:first)').each(function(){
    var numEl = $(this).closest('ul').data('index');
    $(this).css('padding-left', numEl * 20 +'px')
})
```

Instead of looping throug all parent every `div` i check the `ul` index i placed in the `data`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MKK8v/33/

Comment: Ah was just about to suggest using the .css() method, yeah this will do what you want.

Comment: Looks like this will do the trick. Do you have any idea about how efficient this method is? As the hierachy could become very big

Comment: It should be O(n) where n is the number of list items.

Comment: I mean that the speed of the function is linearly related to the number of items in his list. It has to be called for every list item that matches and make a chance to the DOM. So if there are 1000 list items, it makes 1000 calls to the DOM. It's not nearly as efficient as his original hardcoded CSS, but obviously the hardcoded CSS can't scale at all. I think this should be reasonably fast unless you're dealing with really massive lists (think millions).

Comment: @Parallel2ne, Here a fiddle with >1000 items : http://jsfiddle.net/MKK8v/30/. Kinda slow, gonna think of a faster method.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Maybe I missed something? I don't see a dual loop, there's just the one .each() which should loop through all the matching list items. So it's a single loop and it contains a modification to the DOM which is what's making it slightly slow. You could speed it up my having it match all of the list items with the same level of indentation and add the css to all of them at once. The .css() method can do that, though you'd have to change it around a bit.

Comment: There is a loop inside `parentsUntil()` function. That's what's slowing the process. Working on something that do not use a loop inside a loop.

Comment: Could have said it sooner :P the code change a little. The first line become : `$('ul.tree').data('index', 0).find('ul').each(function(){}` and change that line (`var index = $this.parents('ul').length == 0 ? 0 : getIndex($this);`) to : `var index = getIndex($this);`. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MKK8v/34/

Comment: Hey Karl-Andre, I am just trying to allow the user to add a new li (or folder as they see it) do I have to run through your function again for the new li to get its padding?

Comment: Do not rerun the code, it use too much juice. Just run thos two line `var numEl = $(this).closest('ul').data('index');
    $(this).css('padding-left', numEl * 20 +'px')` but change the `$(this)` for the newly added `div`